# <script> tag is shown in ajax response and executed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

now i got this issue actually i don't know why, this is the first time that i faced this issue.

let me explain it to you

- i have ajax request.
- the response of this ajax request will be shown in a div.
- the response is a page contain html, php, js.
- the script is running but the script tag is returned as text.

okay let me explain the problem to you.

> The response has `<script>` but when i called the ajax request the `<script>` shown in the result as text !!!

let me show u my code

**AJAX REQUEST**

```
$.ajax({
    url: getBaseUrl() + 'Pages/book_room',
    async: false,
    data: {offerKey: offerKey, roomType: roomType, hotel: hotel, address: address, stars: stars, checkIn: checkIn, checkOut: checkOut, people: people, image: image, price: price, currency: currency, roomCount: roomCount},
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    beforeSend: function() { 
        $('#' + offerKey).show('slow'); 

    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#' + offerKey).hide('slow', function() {
            $.parseHTML(data, document, true);
            $(this).html(data);
        });
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#' + offerKey).show('slow');
    }
});
```

**THE RESULT**
[image: This is my status ???!!! why this happening]

**UPDATE AJAX TARGET CONTENT**

```
<section id="content" style="background: #fff;">
    <div class="container" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="main" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="booking-section travelo-box">
                    <div class="stepwizard col-md-offset-3">
                        <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
                            <div class="stepwizard-step">
                                <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
                                <p>Personal Information</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stepwizard-step">
                                <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                                <p>Payment Option</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stepwizard-step">
                                <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                                <p>Confimation</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <form id="room_book" class="booking-form" method="POST">
                        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
                            <div class="person-information">
                                <h2>Your Personal Information</h2>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                        <label>first name</label>
                                        <?php
                                            $attr = array(
                                                'type' => "text",
                                                'class' => "input-text full-width",
                                                'value' => set_value('first_name'),
                                                'name' => 'first_name',
                                                'id' => 'first_name'
                                            );
                                            echo form_input($attr); 
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                        <label>last name</label>
                                        <?php
                                            $attr = array(
                                                'type' => "text",
                                                'class' => "input-text full-width",
                                                'value' => set_value('last_name'),
                                                'name' => 'last_name',
                                                'id' => 'last_name'
                                            );
                                            echo form_input($attr); 
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                        <label>email address</label>
                                        <?php
                                            $attr = array(
                                                'type' => "email",
                                                'class' => "input-text full-width",
                                                'value' => set_value('email'),
                                                'name' => 'email',
                                                'id' => 'email'
                                            );
                                            echo form_input($attr); 
                                        ?>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                        <label>Verify E-mail Address</label>
                                        <?php
                                            $attr = array(
                                                'type' => "email",
                                                'class' => "input-text full-width",
                                                'value' => set_value('confirm_email'),
                                                'name' => 'confirm_email',
                                                'id' => 'confirm_email'
                                            );
                                            echo form_input($attr); 
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                        <label>Nationality</label>
                                        <div class="selector">
                                            <input type="text" class="input-text full-width typeahead" id="autocomplete" placeholder="" />
                                            <input type="hidden" id="locationId" name="locationId" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                        <label>Phone number</label>
                                        <?php
                                            $attr = array(
                                                'type' => "text",
                                                'class' => "input-text full-width",
                                                'value' => set_value('phone'),
                                                'name' => 'phone',
                                                'id' => 'phone'
                                            );
                                            echo form_input($attr); 
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                        <label>Date of Birth</label>
                                        <input type="date" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" style="vertical-align: middle;" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                        <label>Prefix</label>
                                        <select name="gender" id="gender" class="input-text full-width">
                                            <option>
                                                Select Prefix
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="Mr">
                                                Mr
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="Ms">
                                                Ms
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="Mrs">
                                                Mrs
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                        <label>Tourest Type</label>
                                        <select name="type" id="type" class="input-text full-width">
                                            <option>
                                                Select Tourest type 
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="adult">
                                                Adult
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="child">
                                                Children
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <?php echo form_checkbox(array('name' => 'offersEmail'), 1, ($this->input->post('offersEmail') ? 1 : 0)); ?>I want to receive <span class="skin-color">Travel Lights</span> promotional offers in the future
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <?php echo form_checkbox(array('name' => 'agreement'), 1, ($this->input->post('offersEmail') ? 1 : 0)); ?> By continuing, you agree to the <a href="#"><span class="skin-color">Terms and Conditions</span></a>.
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="color: red; padding: 15px;">
                                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" style="margin-right: 2%;">Next</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h2>Payment Method</h2>
                                    <?php
                                        foreach ($payment->param->paymentMethod as $method) {
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <?php echo $method->description; ?>
                                                <label class="control-label title" style="text-transform: none;">
                                                    <div style="margin: 0 15px;"><input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" value="<?php echo $method->id; ?>" /> <?php echo $method->name; ?></div>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                                        <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h3> Step 3</h3>
                                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var locationId;
    var locationName;
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function(query, proccess) {
            $.ajax({
                url: getBaseUrl() + 'Pages/get_countries',
                data: {poi: query, order: 'POPULARITY'},
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    proccess(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        updater: function(item) {
            $('#locationId').val(item.id);
            return item.name;
        }
    });
    var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
        allWells = $('.setup-content'),
        allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');
    allWells.hide();
    navListItems.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $item = $(this);
        if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
            navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
            $item.addClass('btn-primary');
            allWells.hide();
            $target.show();
            $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
        }
    });
    allNextBtn.click(function() {
        var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
            curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
            nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
            curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
            isValid = true;
        $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
        for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
            if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
                isValid = false;
                $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            }
        }
        if (isValid) nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
    });
    $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE #2**

by the way the wizard's script is in this scrip tag and it works fine.

[image: this is the script tag in inspect element it shows that the text in script tag]

Comment: Script tags do not execute in AJAX. Instead acts as another Block Level Element.

Comment: Try to remove `dataType: 'html',` and see what it gives. Check if `<script>` and `</script>` are present in this `data` result. For more, Have to know what is the content of the page called by Ajax.

Comment: if you write a script tag in a page and call it from ajax. the script tag will be executed normally.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Scripts called by ajax executes. No problem with it.

Comment: i try to make it withour `dataType` and try to make it with `json` and try to make it with `html` the same result @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: Show your Ajax target content.

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou Inspect the SCRIPT tag and see if you could find any `display: block` or something?

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry for that but when i saw that duplicated to not related question that's why i talk like that, please don't be upset :)

Comment: and for `display: block;` there is no css in my target content

Comment: and the target content is in the question i update it with that, @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou That's the reason I reopened it.

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou What happens when you inspect? Is it inside `<script>` tag or what?

Comment: yeah it's in a script tag in the inspect @PraveenKumar

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou Right side any `display: block`?

Comment: Whoahh! That a big data expected for your `$('#' + offerKey)` div (I suppose it's a div). But size doesn't matter. Try removing `$.parseHTML(data, document, true);`

Comment: @PraveenKumar i add the target as update for my question and there is no `display: block` in it bro

Comment: i try this also i add it when i start get this issue @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: offerKey is something like this `Q0tgRYE03sB3WNzP` that's not a big data for the id attribute and this will never be bigger than this

Comment: Can you provide a live link ?

Comment: i'm sorry this will need time coz i'm working on local and there is big changes happend and if i need to upload it, will need to compare it with the online copy and upload the changes ...etc you know :( @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: I'm in no rush here... If you want to fix this with me, I have to see what's going on in clear. Because what you provided yet looks ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118718/discussion-between-alaa-m-jaddou-and-louys-patrice-bessette).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `<script>` tag is meant to have `display: none` using the User Agent Stylesheet:

[image]

I strongly believe if you inspect the element, you will find that in the **Computed Styles** as I shown above, it will be inheriting `display` styles somehow. That's the reason.

Find something like:

```css
.divClass * {display: block;}
```

Coz, no one targets `<script>` tag! `:P`

Comment: yeah you r right :) this is work perfictly thanks for you time :)

Comment: BTW this is my first time that i heard about script tag taking style :) this is new information could be helpfull :)

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou I was shocked too when I learnt it recently! `:o` Script is just text mate! `:o` ps: The same applies with `<style>`. Try it out.